# Backward compatible postgresql update in a scaled spring microservice

Tags: spring, database, postgresql, microservices, database-migration

I have a spring microservice running in Kubernetes that is horizontally scaled to multiple pods. All the service instances point to a single PostgreSQL database. I am trying to update the name of one column in a table. What's the best way to go around it?

I am mainly concerned about the time when the table is updated but some of the service instances still have older code referencing the previous column name and things will break. This seems like a very common use case but I am not able to find anything concrete.

Answer (score 0):

I see  2 options of doing this migration:

- Instead of updating the existing column, you can just add a new one (with your new name), then deploy the app which uses the new column, then update the table to remove the old column. If you're not using column positions in your queries or something like that, this should work fine.
- If you have millisecond level latency requirements and the DB is not so big, you could create a duplicate of the existing DB that could serve the queries while you update the original DB. Then finally you deploy the app which uses the old DB but with the new column name. This works regardless of the DB type.

Comment: 2nd option is not feasible for me. In first option the issue is that during deployment there will a state when some containers will be running the old code and some container the new code..so the table data will be corrupted.. some data (from old app) will enter data in old columns and request which will land on new app will end up entering data in new column

Comment: During and after the migration you can start a data migration process, which will fully sync both DBs (just copying the data from the old DB to the new one). Eventually, both of them will be the same. I believe the deployment will last for a couple of minutes, so the impact will be probably perceived by an extremely small fraction of a daily traffic